# Could HttpClient Class be used in Periodic Task with Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I got a Periodic Task running some Http Post Tasks, but It seems doesn't work.
I have checked the list of APIs that can be used in Periodic Task, and there's no HttpClient.
However there is WebClient in the list. I guest HttpClient should be allowed to be used.
Thx.

this is my code using httpclient. when i am doing single-step debugging to the

response = await clientPost.PostAsync("http://*******/update", content);

visual studio just leaves the single-step debug mode, and i got none responses...

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await clientPost.PostAsync("http://*******/update", content);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("no networking");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`HttpWebRequest`** API.

Ensure that you stick to the usage of the supported APIs for 2 important reasons:

1. Your App may **fail certification** if a disallowed API is used.
   when you're finally done with your APP, you have to submit it to the WP8 store for certification before it can show up on the marketplace. this is one of the criteria for sign-off that you don't use unsupported APIs.
2. And even if you use it, it may result in runtime exceptions.

Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) MSDN for more details.

Comment: Hi, I don't see System.Net.Http.HttpClient in the unsupported list. And What kind of **fail certification warning** would I get?

Comment: I got a Debug Output "System.Net.Http.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file." when I create a  
 Httpclient object. I wonder if this message means that HttpClient is unsupported.

Comment: i don't see HttpClient here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: when you're finally done with your APP, you have to submit it to the WP8 store for certification before it can show up on the marketplace. this is one of the criteria for sign-off that you don't use unsupported APIs

Comment: hi, I have given up HttpClient, and used the HttpWebRequest. I posted a new question. Could you please help? Thx!  [My new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878186/how-to-post-data-in-periodic-task-with-windows-phone-8)

Comment: glad to help. please close out this post by marking answer.

Comment: Thx! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878186/how-to-post-data-in-periodic-task-with-windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878186/how-to-post-data-in-periodic-task-with-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is supported, but you need to add a reference to the dll. I just add the reference through nuget.

Comment: I have added the reference...But it doesn't work. Now I am trying HttpWebRequest. And It works when I am doing single-step debugging. But doesn't work when I delete the breakpoint.

Comment: And I open a new post for this question, I would appreciate it if you can help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878186/how-to-post-data-in-periodic-task-with-windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878186/how-to-post-data-in-periodic-task-with-windows-phone-8)

Comment: I have updated this post and added some code when  i am using httpclient.